# how to get gap between tab titles on dojo tab container

Tags: javascript, dojo

Dojo tab container puts the page titles next to eachother without space in between.  How to align the tab page titles to the entire width of the tab container so it appears there is equal spaces between each tab.

This is something like 'justify' alignment on paragraph where texts wraps to the full width of a line.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a built-in way to control the spacing of tabs in a TabContainer. If you need to space out the tabs, you could try a solution where you apply relative css positioning to the tabs in order space them out.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply CSS styling to the dijitTab class to alter the tabs of a TabContainer. Just give the TabContainer an ID and use that to access and style the tabs within it. For example:

Declare the TabContainer in HTML:

```
<div id="myTabs" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" ... ></div>
```

Then use the following CSS to set a margin between tabs:

```
#myTabs .dijitTab {
margin-right: 16px;
}
```

Of course you could get more creative with the styling, but this should get you started.

Comment: Yes, CSS is the way to do this. Thanks for the suggestion to you both bitfiddler and @drew.